# Efficient way to create a buffer with a schema and send it over WebSockets in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, websocket, protocol-buffers

I'm writing a browser game and am looking for a way to send raw array buffers to and from the `node.js` server.

I don't like the idea of sending `JSON` strings over `WebSockets` because:

1. I have to specify keys when the receiver already knows the format
2. There is no validation or checking if you send malformed structure (not required though)
3. Parsing JSON strings in to objects is inherently slower than reading binary
4. Wasted bandwidth from the entire payload being a string (instead of packed ints, for example)

Ideally, I would be able to have a schema for every message type, construct that message, and send its raw array buffer to the server. Something like this:

```
schema PlayerAttack {
  required int32 damage;
  required int16[] coords;
  required string name;
}

var message = new PlayerAttack(5, [24, 32], "John");
websockets.send(message.arrayBuffer());
```

And it would then arrive at the Node.js server as a Buffer with the option to decode in to an object.

Google's [Protocol Buffers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs) almost fits this use-case, but are too slow and have too much overhead (7x slower than `JSON.parse` from my benchmark and includes features like tagging which I have no use for).

Comment: It sounds like you may want a binary packer/unpacker that works off some sort of format description.  If you search for "Javascript binary packer", you will find several.  Here's are a couple: https://github.com/pgriess/node-jspack and https://rfw.name/restruct.js/ and https://www.npmjs.com/package/packet

Comment: @jfriend00: Thanks. It definitely helps to know the name of what I'm looking for: "binary packer with format description". I'll look in to these.